# List of Virtual Globes

Tags: web-mapping, globe

I kept a listing of virtual globes in 2005 and 2006, but it's now woefully out of date http://geography2.blogspot.com/2005/11/listing-of-virtual-globes.html. Today, the main four seem to be: Google Earth (proprietary and free), Microsoft Bing Maps 3D (proprietary and free), ESRI ArcGIS Explorer (proprietary and free), and NASA World Wind (free and open source). Many, if not most, are being integrated into the web browser.

What is out there? Any special or particularly innovative capabilities?

Comment: A few additional notes:
Wikipedia listing of virtual globes and capabilities:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_globe

KDE Marble project looks active; uses OpenStreetMap. http://edu.kde.org/marble/

Comment: was just going to answer w/ Marble! +1 on that comment.

Comment: Should be community wiki if you want a list

Comment: While I would hate to discourage potential site users, I think [we would be best served by setting good standards at the beginning](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26/dont-use-community-wiki-until-you-know-what-it-means-here/31#31).

Comment: Sorry @glennon. I appreciate the *sentiment* of encouraging more answers. But getting reputation for simply for being *first* to contribute to a list isn't reason enough to misuse the feature. I converted this to community wiki.

Answer (score 5):

[RATMAN](http://ratman.sourceforge.net/) is a GPLed research project virtual globe, though it hasn't been updated since 2009.

[OSSIM Planet](http://www.ossim.org/OSSIM/ossimPlanet.html), built as part of OSSIM, which [includes an API](http://trac.osgeo.org/ossim/wiki/ossimPlanetAPI) and is the only OSGeo entry to the virtual globe space.

[osgEarth](http://osgearth.org/), an extension of [OpenSceneGraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg) for globes.

There's also this talk at FOSS4G: [Comparison of Open Source Virtual Globe](http://2010.foss4g.org/presentations_show.php?id=3690)s

From the innovation front, better browser integration (Google Earth Plugin & API) and mobile support (including augmented reality) are the largest movements, and hopefully another major change in the next couple of years with the innovation of a WebGL based browser which interoperates on mobile devices.

Comment: BTW: Ratman is both server and client, hence it offers a complete geodata streaming solution

Answer (score 3):

Concerning the new WebGL technology, there are some interesting project here :

WebGLEarth : http://www.webglearth.com/

The WebGL Globe : http://www.chromeexperiments.com/globe

Both are Open Source project.

Answer (score 2):

[Virtual Terrain Project](http://vterrain.org/) - open source project whose aim is *"to foster the creation of tools for easily constructing any part of the real world in interactive, 3D digital form."* The main components of the toolset is [VTBuilder](http://vterrain.org/Doc/VTBuilder/overview.html) to construct virtual environments (doesn't do whole globes in one shot though), and then of course something to cruise around in the world created, [Enviro](http://vterrain.org/Doc/Enviro/overview.html).

Over the course of time the most valuable component of the VTP project to me has not been the tools but the website itself, which has far ranging and pithy thumbnail reviews of [related software](http://vterrain.org/Packages/Com/) (be sure to browse the [other](http://www.vterrain.org/Packages/NonCom/) [categories](http://www.vterrain.org/Packages/GovEdu/) [as](http://www.vterrain.org/Packages/Artificial/) [well](http://www.vterrain.org/Packages/Located/)), [data](http://www.vterrain.org/Locations/int.html), and [research papers](http://www.vterrain.org/Culture/BldCity/Edu/) to name but a few.

Answer (score 2):

[OssimPlanet](http://www.ossim.org/OSSIM/ossimPlanet.html) is an open source project that is built on the Ossim set of libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Marble: http://edu.kde.org/marble/

Answer (score 1):

Two more frameworks:

http://cesiumjs.org is a JavaScript library for creating 3D globes and 2D maps in a web browser without a plugin, based on WebGL

and

http://www.openwebglobe.org also using WebGL

Answer (score 0):

ReadyMap might be another option. [Here](http://demo.pelicanmapping.com/rmweb/webgl/tests/leaflet.html) is an example (with a bonus of Leaflet integration!) [via [@LeafletJS](https://twitter.com/#!/LeafletJS)]:

[image]

And one more with 3D overlay on the globe:

[image]

More: [demos](http://demo.pelicanmapping.com/rmweb/webgl/tests/index.html), [code](https://github.com/gwaldron/godzi-webgl/wiki/ReadyMap-SDK).

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the World Wind Java SDK, not a final application but a powerful toolit to build your custom one.